# PHP that processes HTML form returns 503 error

Tags: php, html, forms, apache

on my website I use a Form to let users send inqiries directly trough the website. For this I use this PHP code to process, named "sendform.php":

```
<?php
    $body = 'Online-Anfrage';
    $body .= '\r\n NAME:';
    $body .= $_POST["input_name"];
    $body .= '\r\n EMAIL:';
    $body .= $_POST["input_email"];
    $body .= '\r\n TELEFON:';
    $body .= $_POST["input_telefon"];
    $body .= '\r\n FAHRZEUG:';
    $body .= $_POST["input_fahrzeug"];
    $body .= '\r\n ERSTZULASSUNG:';
    $body .= $_POST["input_erstzulassung"];
    $body .= '\r\n KILOMETERSTAND:';
    $body .= $_POST["input_kilometerstand"];
    $body .= '\r\n PREISVORSTELLUNG:';
    $body .= $_POST["input_preisvorstellung"];

    $to = "my@mail.de";
    $headers = 'From: info@mmymail.de' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["input_email"] . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $subject = "Online-Anfrage";
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) 
    {
        echo("<p>Wir haben Ihre Anfrage erhalten. Vielen Dank für Ihr vertrauen!    </p>");  
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo("<p>Interner Serverfehler. Bitte rufen Sie uns für eine Anfrage direkt an:</p>");
    }
?>
```

But when I try to use the action="sendform.php" with my index.html I get a server-error 503. The code of the form I use is this one:

```
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="sendform.php">
                    <fieldset>

                    <!-- Form Name -->
                    <legend>Kostenlose und unverbindliche Verkaufsanfrage</legend>

                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="input_name">Name</label>  
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input id="input_name" name="input_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="input_email">E-Mail Adresse</label>  
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input id="input_email" name="input_email" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="input_telefon">Telefonnummer</label>  
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input id="input_telefon" name="input_telefon" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="input_fahrzeug">Fahrzeugmodell</label>  
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input id="input_fahrzeug" name="input_fahrzeug" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="input_erstzulassung">Erstzulassung</label>  
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input id="input_erstzulassung" name="input_erstzulassung" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">
                      <span class="help-block">Bitte Monat und Jahr angeben.</span>  
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Appended Input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="input_kilometerstand">Kilometerstand</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <input id="input_kilometerstand" name="input_kilometerstand" class="form-control" placeholder="" type="text" required="">
                          <span class="input-group-addon">km</span>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Appended Input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="input_preisvorstellung">Preisvorstellung</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <input id="input_preisvorstellung" name="input_preisvorstellung" class="form-control" placeholder="" type="text" required="">
                          <span class="input-group-addon">€</span>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-md-12">Anfrage absenden!</button>

                    </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

I have absolutely no idea how to fix this actually since I cannot find any errors in the namings or so, there must be something else causing this error.

The server log does not say anything like "parse error" or so, what you get when there is something wrong with the variables..

EDIT: I do recieve emails but they are only filled with the static text, the variables do not exist in the mails that i recieve

Could you help me with this? Thank!

Comment: Can you provide any Apache error log information?

Comment: Since the website runs on a shared webhost I cannot access the logfiles :-/ I have only access to the errorlogs and these are empty..

Comment: Have you successfully sent email with PHP using this host before?

Comment: Yes, actually edited my post: EDIT: I do recieve emails but they are only filled with the static text, the variables do not exist in the mails that i recieve

Answer (score 0):

The Web server (running the Web site) is currently unable to handle the HTTP request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay. Some servers in this state may also simply refuse the socket connection, in which case a different error may be generated because the socket creation timed out.

[click here for details and how to remove](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/503error.htm)

[and also this](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html)

Comment: Well I actually know what the error 503 does say but my server gives the error but is also processing the php (i do recieve the mails but the variables are missing)

Comment: first print the post info by adding these lines at the begining of your sendform.php file.ie, <?php echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);... Then find whats the error.